# How to count received Notifications in Android and set icon badge

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app which  received notifications in notification bar,but i want to count notifications and set badge icons number of notifications , I'm using library ShortcutBadge, but only 1 number showing on icons app. How to count received notifications and set count notifications on icon app.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import me.leolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public final class NotificationMaker {


private NotificationMaker() throws InstantiationException {
    throw new InstantiationException("This class is not created for instantiation");
}

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
public static void showNotification(Context context, User user, String fromName, String subject) {



    Settings settings = new Settings(context);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
    mBuilder.setTicker(context.getString(R.string.notification_ticker_new_email));

    mBuilder.setContentTitle(fromName + " to " + user.getUsername());

    mBuilder.setContentText(subject);
    mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse(settings.getString(Settings.KEY_NOTIFICATION_SOUND)));
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(LoginActivity.class);

    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    int count=1;
    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context,count);



    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify((int) (System.currentTimeMillis()), mBuilder.build());

    CurrentUser.setCurrentUser(user, context);


}
```

Comment: save count in shared preference and update in 
    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context,count);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the count size by yourself. You can use SharedPreferences. For example, you need read the previous count from your SharedPreferences with something like this:

```
// You need to use this import
//import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

// Read previous value. If not found, use 0 as default value.
int count = prefs.getInt("count_key", 0);

// because you need to show the badge again, it means you need
// to increment the count
count = count + 1;

// Then apply it
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, count);

// After that, you need to save the value again for another badge count
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("count_key", count);
editor.commit();
```